# Spring Integration: the SecurityContext propagation

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-integration

I have some perplexity about the SecurityContext propagation in Spring Integration.

Here is the point of the documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#security-context-propagation

My perplexity are the following:

> **(1)** To be sure that our interaction with the application is secure,
>   according to its security system rules, we should supply some security
>   context with an authentication (principal)    object. The Spring
>   Security project provides a flexible, canonical mechanism to
>   authenticate our application clients over HTTP, WebSocket or SOAP
>   protocols (as can be done for     any other integration protocol with a
>   simple Spring Security extension) and it provides a SecurityContext
>   for further authorization checks on the application objects,      such as
>   message channels.     By default, the SecurityContext is tied with the
>   current Thread's execution state using the
>   (ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy).   It is accessed by an AOP
>   interceptor on secured methods to check if that principal of the
>   invocation has sufficent permissions to call that method, for example.
>     **This works well with the current thread**, **but often**, processing logic
>   **can be performed** on another thread or even on several threads, or on
>   **to some external system(s)**.

This means that the SecurityContext (normally) is accessible only for the current Thread. Right?

So, how to make it accessible for another thread of another application (integrated with Spring Integration) ?

> **(2)** Standard thread-bound behavior is easy to configure if our application is built on the Spring Integration components and its
>   message channels.     **In this case, the secured objects may be any
>   service activator or transformer**, secured with a
>   `MethodSecurityInterceptor` in their  
>     (see Section 8.8, “Adding Behavior to Endpoints”) or even
>   `MessageChannel` (see Section D.2, “Securing channels” above).    When
>   using DirectChannel communication, the SecurityContext is available
>   automatically, because the downstream flow runs on the current thread.
>     But in case of the QueueChannel, ExecutorChannel and
>   PublishSubscribeChannel with an Executor, messages are transferred
>   from one thread to another (or several) by the nature of      those
>   channels.     In order to support such scenarios, **we can either transfer
>   an Authentication object within the message headers and extract and
>   authenticate it on the other side before secured object access**. 
>     **Or, we can propagate the SecurityContext to the thread receiving the
>   transferred message**.

This means that we have to extract the Principal manually? If yes, how?

Or it's enough to use the propagation aspect, from 4.2 version?

> **(3)** Starting with version 4.2 **SecurityContext propagation** has been
>   introduced.   It is implemented as a
>   `SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor`, **which can simply be
>   added to any `MessageChannel` or configured as a
>   `@GlobalChannelInterceptor`**.    The logic of this interceptor is based on
>   the SecurityContext extraction from the current thread from the
>   `preSend()` method, and its populating to another thread from the
>   `postReceive()`   (beforeHandle()) method.    Actually, this interceptor
>   is an extension of the more generic
>   ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor, which wraps the
>   message-to-send together with the state-to-propagate      in an internal
>   Message extension - MessageWithThreadState, - on one side and
>   extracts the original message back and state-to-propagate on another. 
>     The ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor can be extended for any
>   context propagation use-case and
>   SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor is a good sample on the
>   matter.

*"Starting with version 4.2 SecurityContext propagation has been introduced."* => Ok, very well.

But: *"It is implemented as a SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor, which can simply be added to any MessageChannel or configured as a @GlobalChannelInterceptor."*

What does it mean? I have to implement an interceptor that extends "SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor" ?

What I have to "add" in my `<int:channel>` configuration?

And if I use `<int:channel-interceptor>` (the same of @GlobalChannelInterceptor), it's different from using `<int:interceptors>` ?

Other perplexity:

*"The logic of this interceptor is based on the SecurityContext extraction from the current thread from the preSend() method, and its populating to another thread from the postReceive()
    (beforeHandle()) method."*

But why there are a *`"obtainPropagatingContext"`* method and a *`"populatePropagatedContext"`* method in the `SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor` class?
Where is made the propagation? In the preSend() / postReceive() methods, or in those two methods?

Furthermore, I tried to propagate the SecurityContext to an external application, without success...

Any explanations about this argument would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of questions here, but let me try to answer to them.

1. What does it mean? I have to implement an interceptor that extends "SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor" ?

No, there is such an interceptor in the Framework out-of-the-box. What you have to do to understand how to add interceptor to `MessageChannel`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-interceptors.

Or like this:

```
@Bean
@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = {
        "#{'queueChannel'}",
        "${security.channel:executorChannel}",
        "publishSubscribeChannel" })
public ChannelInterceptor securityContextPropagationInterceptor() {
    return new SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor();
}
```

See their JavaDocs for more information.

2. But why there are a "obtainPropagatingContext" method and a "populatePropagatedContext" method in the SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor class?

`SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor extends ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor<Authentication>` , where `obtainPropagatingContext` and `populatePropagatedContext` are just generic method to extract some current `State` in the `preSend()` (on Thread) and provide that `State` for population/manipulation in the `postReceive()`, which may happen in the different Thread.

3. Yes, `SecurityContext` is thread-bound in Spring Security and the logic to be sure that we can perform a secured function is fully based on the `ThreadLocal` variable. That's why we have to transfer it that way. The "propagation" is a process not state.

Not sure what you mean about "external application", but there is only one mechanism to do that: send credentials together with the request to that application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Artem. But how to "send credentials together with the request"? It's intended to be with manual management, or it can be configured?

Comment: Manual. The `<header-enricher>` can help you to populate credential (or token) into headers and send message to the external system. Also you can consider transfer full `SecurityContext` since it is `Serializable`, but it's not so flexible in case of surrogate integration.

Comment: Interesting suggestion! I'm trying to add a `<header-enricher>` in a `<int:chain>` (in which I innested the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` ), the header is correctly added but only for the current Context... The URL called by int-http:outbound-gateway has no the enriched header.

Comment: Well, it's a bit different story, but you should take care about your custom headers mapping to allow them transfer over HTTP: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping